# Change color textview based on position or flag

Tags: android, textview, background-color

I have created textviews dynamically based on array values.

Its displayed fine. My problem is 
If suppose i have 5 values in my array along with flag values (i.e 0 and 1)

If i click on textview index 2, it contains flag '0' means display in red color and which index contains '1' need to display in green color.

How to achieve this? I have tried a lot.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
                final TextView textView = new TextView(Activity.this);
                int parentLayoutHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                        Constants.DRAWER_LIST_ITEM_LAYOUT_HEIGHT_DIP, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, parentLayoutHeight);
                params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 20);
                textView.setLayoutParams(params);
                textView.setText(array.get(i).getOptions());
                textView.setTag(array.get(i).getFlag());
                textView.setId(Integer.parseInt(array.get(i).getId()));
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                textView.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
                textView.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 20);
                textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, Constants.DRAWER_LIST_ITEM_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
                textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_rectangle_1);
                textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
                            if (parsedAnswers.get(i).getFlag().equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
                                textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_rectangle_red);
                            }else{
                                textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_rectangle_green);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                mLayout.addView(textView);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
      textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
      for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        if (parsedAnswers.get(i).getFlag().equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
          textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_rectangle_red);
        }else{
          textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_rectangle_green);
        }
      }
    }
```

I think that what you need is the tag of textview, instead of doing a loop, which is linked to the parsedAnswers, like:

```
String tag = (String)textView.getTag();
if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
    textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_rectangle_red);
}else{
    textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_rectangle_green);
}
```

and if your array is changing dynamically you could only set the position inside like:

```
textView.setTag(i);
```

and in the listener

```
int position = (Integer)textView.getTag();
if (parsedAnswers.get(position).getFlag().equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
   textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_rectangle_red);
}else{
    textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_rectangle_green);
}
```

also for changing the color of the text instead of background, you can use textView.setTextColor(color)

Comment: I fixed this, but anyway thanks a lot for your answer. I tried your answer also its working, accepted it may help someone also.